# Should StackExchange site shortcuts be working in Meta, here?

Tags: support

In [this thread](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133/what-lessons-could-we-learn-from-sites-like-judaism-se), I tried using a few StackExchange site shortcuts, like below:

`[Judaism.SE] [Christianity.SE] [Parenting.SE] [Philosophy.SE] [Skeptics.SE]`

However, they just ended up appearing exactly as I'd typed them instead of converting into SE site links:

> [Judaism.SE] [Christianity.SE] [Parenting.SE] [Philosophy.SE] [Skeptics.SE]

I've tested the feature in chat, and it seems to work fine.  Is this something not available to Private Betas, or to Meta sites, or is it a chat-only feature?

Or, is this a bug?

**EDIT**

Testing some stuff suggested by @Shog9 below.

`https://judaism.stackexchange.com/ https://christianity.stackexchange.com/ https://parenting.stackexchange.com/ https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ http://skeptics.stackexchange.com`

> https://judaism.stackexchange.com/ https://christianity.stackexchange.com/ https://parenting.stackexchange.com/ https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/ http://skeptics.stackexchange.com

Comment: [Judaism.SE] [Christianity.SE] [Parenting.SE] [Philosophy.SE] [Skeptics.SE] - see, they work... *In comments!* There's no support for them in actual *posts* though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me refer you to [the Markdown help page](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). These shortcuts are listed under the section, "Comment Formatting" - that is, they work *in comments*.

In normal posts, just paste a link to the site itself.

Comment: Well, that just seems like the long way around.  It's much easier & shorter to write `[Christianity.SE]` than `http://christianity.stackexchange.com/` no matter where you are writing it - so, why only allow it in chat/comments?

Comment: @Iszi: I suspect this is because there's more benefit to be had in comments. Specifically, comments are often used to refer folks to other sites (think: "this is off-topic on Stack Overflow, but try asking on [gardening.se]") There's less call for it in body text, where you're expected to be putting more time into writing and formatting anyway.

Comment: Tested pasting links (see above) and that doesn't do the job either.  In fact, the URLs don't even get consistently hyperlinked in my post.

Comment: Don't put ticmarks around them! If you want to be sure they hyperlink, either surround each one with angle-brackets (`<...>`) or use one of the more full-featured hyperlinking syntaxes (see [the help page](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links)).

Comment: The tick marks are just to show in the post what the code I'm testing is going to be.  I've block-quoted the part that should represent the test results.  Still, I'd like to see the hyperlinks behave the same way the other feature works in comments.  Guess there's no hope for that?

Comment: I'm not gonna say there's *no hope* - there just hasn't been much call for it. Feel free to suggest it if you like... FWIW, [here's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000) the original feature request for these links in *comments* - you might be able to re-use some of the arguments from the discussion (or not).